# Double IF statements - only the first one works

Tags: c++, if-statement

Here's my problem: The program requires login info. The username verification works fine - when a bad username is given it is rejected and the user is asked to retry. However, when the password prompt appears, any given character is accepted - even just hitting the ENTER key will get you logged in. Can anyone spot my error??

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int e;

    string x;
    string userName;
    string userPass;

    i = 1;
    e = 1;

    cout << "Please enter your information to login.\n";
    //First 'do' is so that the line "Please enter your info..." does not get repeated
    do
    {
        //This 'do' is to loop through the login process until successful
        do
        {
            cout << "Username: ";
            getline (cin, userName);

            //Checks for a successfully input username
            if (userName == "Fin")
            {
                cout << "Password: ";
                getline (cin, userPass);

                //Checks for a successfully input password
                // HERE'S WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
                if (userPass == "fin123");
                {

                    cout << "Login successful.\n" << "Press ENTER to exit.";
                    //Waits for user to hit the ENTER key before exiting
                    getline (cin, x);
                    if (x.empty())
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                //If the password is incorrect, start the login loop over
                if (userPass != "financiero123")
                {
                    cout << "Incorrect password. Please try again.";
                    //Waits for user to press a key before starting over
                    cin.get();
                    e = 0;
                }
            }
            //If the username is incorrect, start the login loop over
            if (userName != "Financiero")
            {
                cout << "Incorrect username. Please try again.";
                //Waits for user to press a key before starting over
                cin.get();
                e = 0;
            }
        } while (e != 0);
        e = 1;
    } while (e != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check for superfluous semicolons.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Your code should compile with zero warnings (a warning is a logical error in your thinking). You can get the compiler to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (userPass == "fin123");
{
    // ...
```

The semicolon after the conditional closes the conditional, so what is left becomes an anonymous block.  It's as though you had written this:

```
if (userPass == "fin123") { }
{
    // ...
```

Therefore the block following this line is executed unconditionally.

Remove the semicolon to correct the logic error.

(Compiling with the `-Wempty-body` flag would have warned about this.)